# c++ limit process child ignore SIGXCPU

Tags: c++

I have this code

```
static void sigXCPU(int pTmp){
  cout<<" .... ";
}

.....
pid_t vPid=fork(); 
  int vStat;   

  switch(vPid){
  case -1: perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  case 0:
    //limit on data
    struct rlimit vLimD;
    vLimD.rlim_cur = 100000; 
    vLimD.rlim_max =  1000000; 
    setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &vLimD);
    //limit on cpu time
    struct rlimit vLimCPU;
    vLimCPU.rlim_cur = 1;
    vLimCPU.rlim_max = 1;

    execl("./p1","",NULL);    
    if(signal(SIGXCPU,sigXCPU)==SIG_ERR);
    break;
  default: 
    while(wait(&vStat)!=vPid);
    break;}
```

and the code for p1 is

```
int main(){
  sleep(10);
return 0;}
```

Why does the child ignore SIGXCPU?The code are compiled with  gcc under FreeBsd 8.0 amd64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the child after `execl` is never executed, because the current process image is replaced with the application in `p1`.

Even if you were to put the signal handler before the `execl`, it would be overriden, because signal dispositions are reset to their defaults after an exec. After all, your handler function would no longer exist in the new process image.

Finally, to set up a signal handler, avoid using `signal` and use [sigaction](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction), instead.

Comment: +1. Particularly so for the edit where you added a discussion of "fixing" (in quotes) the code so the call to `signal` is made before the call to `execl`.

Comment: @David, I also recommended the use of `sigaction` instead of `signal` for adding a handler, in the spirit of further education.

Comment: Saw that. Not that it will help with this problem. To xnl96: Just about the only code you should have after the call to `exec` is a call to `exit`, possibly prefaced with an error message. Returning from `exec` only happens when something went very wrong with the `exec`.

Comment: To add to David's comment, exec can fail when for some reason you cannot execute the application (e.g., the executable file does not have compatible exec privileges for your user / group or it doesn't exist).